# How to unbind this from a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm binding this to resize function, but how to remove or unbind this from a resize function. I am binding this in some frequently calling method and every time I want to clear this from resize function before bind this. 
I want bind this to resize function but only time, this can be used in setInterval.

```
function resize() {
 // some process
}
// I want to unbind this from resize, before going to bind again
resize = resize.bind(this);
```

Comment: why not keep the original function?

Comment: Unless you implement your own version of `.bind()`, you cannot "un-bind" a function.

Comment: try `resize = resize.bind(undefined);`

Comment: thanks guys, i will try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unbind() .hover() but not .click()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233600/how-to-unbind-hover-but-not-click)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `bind()` creates a new function, you can do the following:

```
function resize() {
 // some process
}

// Bound
const boundResize = resize.bind(this);

// Unbound
const unboundresize = resize;
```

Thus the method is not "bound", when you invoke `bind()` you are creating a **new** function, not editing the original one context.

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: There is no problem mate, this is how javascript works.

Answer (score -2):

You can use

`resize = resize.bind(undefined)`

to unbind the `this` and the again use `.bind` to bind `this`

Comment: This will not return to the previous `this` context. Will create a new `this` which will equal to `undefined`.

Comment: to assign previous this context you have to store the previous context at the time of assigning

Comment: there is no assignment as `bind()` provides a brand new method in its return value. Original method is the same as before.